# Proper way to address a class methods and properties from another method within a method

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Imagine I have a class with two methods / functions. One method utilizes another class's function - in this case JQuery's ajax-call. Inside this function I want to address a method of my own class.

```
class priceSearch {


  this foobar = "null";

  loadStuff() {

    $.ajax({url: requestUrl})
      .done(function(response){

        this.processStuff(response);
        console.log(foobar); // -> undefined
      });

  }

  processStuff(stuff) {

    console.log(stuff);

  }

}
```

But this will lead to

> processStuff is not defined

Apparently, because processStuff is not part of ajax.done and "this" references the ajax.done.

So, how do I address parent's class method?

Same for properties: foobar from within the Ajax call will return "undefined".

Comment: Try using an arrow function `.done((response) => {/* Body */})`, if I am not mistaken it will bind it to your class instead of the `jQuery` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an anonymous function to ajax.done, `this` is not shared between a class and an anonymous function. You can either:

1. Declare a function `handleResponse` inside your class and pass that by calling `ajax.done(this.handleResponse)`
2. Use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to change the `this` value inside the anonymous function
3. Use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), they share the scope and `this` instance instead of defining their own, something like:

```
ajax.done(response => {
    // whatever you wanna do
});
```

Comment: The fact the function is anonymous is an irrelevance, try giving it a name and you'll see the exact same problem. The problem is that it's passed as a callback to `done`, which therefore controls how the function is called and therefore what its `this` is. (In particular, it won't be called in the context of the `priceSearch` "class")

Comment: thanks. #3 - Arraow functions does the trick. Seems also the cleanest way to me.

Comment: @RobinZigmond functions by default have their own ```this```, giving it a name doesn't make a difference. I simply meant to state that ```this``` is not shared between class and a function which is not declared as it's method (or declared as a arrow function). However, passing it to ```ajax.done``` is not what causes it's ```this``` to change. You can declare a function and call it within the class' method and it'll still have a different ```this```. OTOH, you can declare a class method ```handleResponse``` and pass it like ajax.done(this.handleResponse), and it'll have the correct ```this```

Comment: No function has "its own `this`* though. The value of `this` depends entirely on how the function is called - the same function can appear to have several different values for `this` if it is called in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

the moment the code enters the anonymous function:

```
.done(function(response){
   *this* is no longer referring to the class but "this" function
});
```

ES6 Solution would be to avoid using anonymous functions for your done and use array functions instead.

```
.done( (response) => {
    this.processStuff(response); *this* still refers to class
});
```

To give you another perspective, in the olden days we would declare a local variable (local to your method) that holds that other method.

```
loadStuff() {
    var psHolder = this.processStuff;
    $.ajax({url: requestUrl})
      .done(function(response){
         psHolder(response);  *this should also work*
      });

}
```

Comment: thanks, I thought about this, too. But it seems not clean to me, because there are a couple of properties and methods I had to address like this.